# Spread out density plots with ggplot

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I saw this great plot from fivethirty that has a slight overlap of density plots for different colleges.  Check out [this link at fivethirtyeight.com](http://fivethirtyeight.com/features/the-most-conservative-and-most-liberal-elite-law-schools)

How would you replicate this plot with *ggplot2*?

Specifically how would you get that **slight overlap**,  *facet_wrap* isn't going to work.

```
TestFrame <-  
  data.frame(
    Score =
      c(rnorm(100, 0, 1)
        ,rnorm(100, 0, 2)
        ,rnorm(100, 0, 3)
        ,rnorm(100, 0, 4)
        ,rnorm(100, 0, 5))
    ,Group =
      c(rep('Ones', 100)
        ,rep('Twos', 100)
        ,rep('Threes', 100)
        ,rep('Fours', 100)
        ,rep('Fives', 100))
  )

ggplot(TestFrame, aes(x = Score, group = Group)) +
  geom_density(alpha = .75, fill = 'black')
```

[image: Partially overlaid density]

Comment: Kind of think you would have to program something on your own using `grid`. It would not be terribly complicated if stuck to a rigid set of options for labels, axes, etc. But it would be work.

Comment: `grid` would be the elegant way to do this in the long run, but you could do it much more easily in the short run with base R tools (`density` + `polygon`).  Would you accept such an answer?

Comment: We did this exact same thing for the cover of our report:  http://www.verizonenterprise.com/DBIR/. I'll see if i can get permission to share the code otherwise i'll mock something up.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As always with ggplot, the key is getting the data in the right format, and then the plotting is pretty straightforward. I'm sure there would be another way to do this, but my approach was to do the density estimation with `density()` and then to make a sort of manual `geom_density()` with `geom_ribbon()`, which takes a `ymin` and `ymax`, necessary for moving the shape off the x axis.

The rest of the challenge was in getting the order of the printing correct, since it seems that ggplot will print the widest ribbon first. In the end, the part that requires the bulkiest code is the production of the quartiles.

I also produced some data that is a bit more consistent with the original figure.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(broom)
rawdata <- data.frame(Score = rnorm(1000, seq(1, 0, length.out = 10), sd = 1),
                  Group = rep(LETTERS[1:10], 10000))

df <- rawdata %>% 
  mutate(GroupNum = rev(as.numeric(Group))) %>% #rev() means the ordering will be from top to bottom
  group_by(Group, GroupNum) %>% 
  do(tidy(density(.$Score, bw = diff(range(.$Score))/20))) %>% #The original has quite a large bandwidth
  group_by() %>% 
  mutate(ymin = GroupNum * (max(y) / 1.5), #This constant controls how much overlap between groups there is
         ymax = y + ymin,
         ylabel = ymin + min(ymin)/2,
         xlabel = min(x) - mean(range(x))/2) #This constant controls how far to the left the labels are

#Get quartiles
labels <- rawdata %>% 
  mutate(GroupNum = rev(as.numeric(Group))) %>% 
  group_by(Group, GroupNum) %>% 
  mutate(q1 = quantile(Score)[2],
         median = quantile(Score)[3],
         q3 = quantile(Score)[4]) %>%
  filter(row_number() == 1) %>% 
  select(-Score) %>% 
  left_join(df) %>% 
  mutate(xmed = x[which.min(abs(x - median))],
         yminmed = ymin[which.min(abs(x - median))],
         ymaxmed = ymax[which.min(abs(x - median))]) %>% 
  filter(row_number() == 1)

p <- ggplot(df, aes(x, ymin = ymin, ymax = ymax)) + geom_text(data = labels, aes(xlabel, ylabel, label = Group)) +


geom_vline(xintercept = 0, size = 1.5, alpha = 0.5, colour = "#626262") + 
  geom_vline(xintercept = c(-2.5, -1.25, 1.25, 2.5), size = 0.75, alpha = 0.25, colour = "#626262") + 
  theme(panel.grid = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_rect(fill = "#F0F0F0"),
        axis.text.y = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        axis.title = element_blank())
for (i in unique(df$GroupNum)) {
  p <- p + geom_ribbon(data = df[df$GroupNum == i,], aes(group = GroupNum), colour = "#F0F0F0", fill = "black") +
    geom_segment(data = labels[labels$GroupNum == i,], aes(x = xmed, xend = xmed, y = yminmed, yend = ymaxmed), colour = "#F0F0F0", linetype = "dashed") +
    geom_segment(data = labels[labels$GroupNum == i,], x = min(df$x), xend = max(df$x), aes(y = ymin, yend = ymin), size = 1.5, lineend = "round") 
}
p <- p + geom_text(data = labels[labels$Group == "A",], aes(xmed - xlabel/50, ylabel), 
                   label = "Median", colour = "#F0F0F0", hjust = 0, fontface = "italic", size = 4)
```

**Edit**
I noticed the original actually does a bit of fudging by stretching out each distribution with a horizontal line (you can see a join if you look closely...). I added something similar with the second `geom_segment()` in the loop.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Although there is a great & accepted answer available already - I finished my contribution as an alternative avenue without data reformatting.

[image]

```
TestFrame <-  
  data.frame(
    Score =
      c(rnorm(50, 3, 2)+rnorm(50, -1, 3)
        ,rnorm(50, 3, 2)+rnorm(50, -2, 3)
        ,rnorm(50, 3, 2)+rnorm(50, -3, 3)
        ,rnorm(50, 3, 2)+rnorm(50, -4, 3)
        ,rnorm(50, 3, 2)+rnorm(50, -5, 3))
    ,Group =
      c(rep('Ones', 50)
        ,rep('Twos', 50)
        ,rep('Threes', 50)
        ,rep('Fours', 50)
        ,rep('Fives', 50))
  )

require(ggplot2)
require(grid)

spacing=0.05

tm <- theme(legend.position="none",     axis.line=element_blank(),axis.text.x=element_blank(),
            axis.text.y=element_blank(),axis.ticks=element_blank(),
            axis.title.x=element_blank(),axis.title.y=element_blank(),
            panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), 
            panel.background = element_blank(), 
            plot.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent",colour = NA),
            plot.margin = unit(c(0,0,0,0),"mm"))

firstQuintile = quantile(TestFrame$Score,0.2)
secondQuintile = quantile(TestFrame$Score,0.4)
median  = quantile(TestFrame$Score,0.5)
thirdQuintile = quantile(TestFrame$Score,0.6)
fourthQuintile = quantile(TestFrame$Score,0.8)

ymax <- 1.5*max(density(TestFrame[TestFrame$Group=="Ones",]$Score)$y)
xmax <- 1.2*max(TestFrame$Score)
xmin <- 1.2*min(TestFrame$Score)

p0 <- ggplot(TestFrame[TestFrame$Group=="Ones",], aes(x = Score, group = Group)) + geom_density(fill = "transparent",colour = NA)+ylim(0-5*spacing,ymax)+xlim(xmin,xmax)+tm
p0 <- p0 + geom_vline(aes(xintercept=firstQuintile),color="gray",size=1.2)
p0 <- p0 + geom_vline(aes(xintercept=secondQuintile),color="gray",size=1.2)
p0 <- p0 + geom_vline(aes(xintercept=thirdQuintile),color="gray",size=1.2)
p0 <- p0 + geom_vline(aes(xintercept=fourthQuintile),color="gray",size=1.2)
p0 <- p0 + geom_vline(aes(xintercept=median),color="darkgray",size=2)
#previous line is a little hack for creating a working empty grid with proper sizing
p1 <- ggplot(TestFrame[TestFrame$Group=="Ones",], aes(x = Score, group = Group)) + geom_density(alpha = .85, fill = 'black', color="white",size=1)+tm+ylim(0,ymax)+xlim(xmin,xmax)+ geom_segment(aes(y=0,x=median(Score),yend=max(density(Score)$y),xend=median(Score)), color="white", linetype=2)
p2 <- ggplot(TestFrame[TestFrame$Group=="Twos",], aes(x = Score, group = Group)) + geom_density(alpha = .85, fill = 'black', color="white",size=1)+tm+ylim(0,ymax)+xlim(xmin,xmax)+ geom_segment(aes(y=0,x=median(Score),yend=max(density(Score)$y),xend=median(Score)), color="white", linetype=2)
p3 <- ggplot(TestFrame[TestFrame$Group=="Threes",], aes(x = Score, group = Group)) + geom_density(alpha = .85, fill = 'black', color="white",size=1)+tm+ylim(0,ymax)+xlim(xmin,xmax)+ geom_segment(aes(y=0,x=median(Score),yend=max(density(Score)$y),xend=median(Score)), color="white", linetype=2)
p4 <- ggplot(TestFrame[TestFrame$Group=="Fours",], aes(x = Score, group = Group)) + geom_density(alpha = .85, fill = 'black', color="white",size=1)+tm+ylim(0,ymax)+xlim(xmin,xmax)+ geom_segment(aes(y=0,x=median(Score),yend=max(density(Score)$y),xend=median(Score)), color="white", linetype=2)
p5 <- ggplot(TestFrame[TestFrame$Group=="Fives",], aes(x = Score, group = Group)) + geom_density(alpha = .85, fill = 'black', color="white",size=1)+tm+ylim(0,ymax)+xlim(xmin,xmax)+ geom_segment(aes(y=0,x=median(Score),yend=max(density(Score)$y),xend=median(Score)), color="white", linetype=2)

f <- grobTree(ggplotGrob(p1))
g <- grobTree(ggplotGrob(p2))
h <- grobTree(ggplotGrob(p3))
i <- grobTree(ggplotGrob(p4))
j <- grobTree(ggplotGrob(p5))



a1 <- annotation_custom(grob = f, xmin = xmin, xmax = xmax,ymin = -spacing, ymax = ymax)
a2 <- annotation_custom(grob = g, xmin = xmin, xmax = xmax,ymin = -spacing*2, ymax = ymax-spacing)
a3 <- annotation_custom(grob = h, xmin = xmin, xmax = xmax,ymin = -spacing*3, ymax = ymax-spacing*2)
a4 <- annotation_custom(grob = i, xmin = xmin, xmax = xmax,ymin = -spacing*4, ymax = ymax-spacing*3)
a5 <- annotation_custom(grob = j, xmin = xmin, xmax = xmax,ymin = -spacing*5, ymax = ymax-spacing*4)

pfinal <- p0 + a1 + a2 + a3 + a4 + a5
pfinal
```

Comment: That is looking really sharp.  Any idea on how to add the overall median and quartiles?

Answer (score 1):

Using dedicated *geom_joy()* from [ggjoy package](https://github.com/clauswilke/ggjoy):

```
library(ggjoy)

ggplot(TestFrame, aes(Score, Group)) +
  geom_joy()
```

[image]

```
# dummy data
set.seed(1)
TestFrame <-  
  data.frame(
    Score =
      c(rnorm(100, 0, 1)
        ,rnorm(100, 0, 2)
        ,rnorm(100, 0, 3)
        ,rnorm(100, 0, 4)
        ,rnorm(100, 0, 5))
    ,Group =
      c(rep('Ones', 100)
        ,rep('Twos', 100)
        ,rep('Threes', 100)
        ,rep('Fours', 100)
        ,rep('Fives', 100))
  )

head(TestFrame)
#        Score Group
# 1 -0.6264538  Ones
# 2  0.1836433  Ones
# 3 -0.8356286  Ones
# 4  1.5952808  Ones
# 5  0.3295078  Ones
# 6 -0.8204684  Ones
```

Comment: You must be reflecting on this question too. Joy plots seem to have gone mainstream.