# Comparing 17 density plots in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, density-plot

I have a list called my_list of 17 dataframes, each of which contains a "HEIGHT" column. I want to compare the density plots of HEIGHT for each dataframe in the style (roughly) of

https://github.com/halhen/viz-pub/blob/master/sports-time-of-day/out.png

Currently,  I've figured out how to make a terrible looking ggplot of all 17 density plots:

```
library(tidyverse)

PR2016_demo_data <- read.csv("DRAFT_PR2016_demo_data.csv")
PR2016_demo_data <- arrange(PR2016_demo_data, CORAL_CD)

species_vector <- c("ACR CERV", "ACR PALM", "ORB ANNU","ORB FRAN", "ORB FAVE", "MYC FERO", "DEN CYLI", "STE INTE", "SID SIDE", "POR ASTR", "MON CAVE", "MEA MEAN", "COL NATA", "PSE STRI", "DIP LABY", "AGA AGAR", "DIC STOK")

my_list <- list()

for (i in 1:17)
{
  my_list[[i]] <- subset(PR2016_demo_data, CORAL_CD == species_vector[i])
}

ggplot(data = my_list[[1]], mapping = aes(x = HEIGHT)) +
  geom_density() + 
  geom_density(data = my_list[[2]], mapping = aes(x = HEIGHT)) +
  geom_density(data = my_list[[3]], mapping = aes(x = HEIGHT)) +
  geom_density(data = my_list[[4]], mapping = aes(x = HEIGHT)) +
  geom_density(data = my_list[[5]], mapping = aes(x = HEIGHT)) +
  geom_density(data = my_list[[6]], mapping = aes(x = HEIGHT)) +
  geom_density(data = my_list[[7]], mapping = aes(x = HEIGHT)) +
  geom_density(data = my_list[[8]], mapping = aes(x = HEIGHT)) +
  geom_density(data = my_list[[9]], mapping = aes(x = HEIGHT)) +
  geom_density(data = my_list[[10]], mapping = aes(x = HEIGHT)) +
  geom_density(data = my_list[[11]], mapping = aes(x = HEIGHT)) +
  geom_density(data = my_list[[12]], mapping = aes(x = HEIGHT)) +
  geom_density(data = my_list[[13]], mapping = aes(x = HEIGHT)) +
  geom_density(data = my_list[[14]], mapping = aes(x = HEIGHT)) +
  geom_density(data = my_list[[15]], mapping = aes(x = HEIGHT)) +
  geom_density(data = my_list[[16]], mapping = aes(x = HEIGHT)) +
  geom_density(data = my_list[[17]], mapping = aes(x = HEIGHT))
```

But I don't understand all the fancy stuff halhen did, so I would appreciate the help.

Comment: Please be more specific. What do you not understand? You already have the plots

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33619980/spread-out-density-plots-with-ggplot/33620824#33620824

Comment: My apologies, I meant that I wanted to be able to see them as in the github plot, where the density plots are arranged vertically so it is easy to compare where the peak of one species height distribution compares to the peak of another species height distribution

Comment: Thanks CMichael - but how do I do that from the data in the form I have?

Comment: I apologize, I did not realize the other question had been posted. But I am still having trouble translating those approaches to my data, if anyone would be so kind as to be more explicit?